# Can I use list-style-type to div tag?

Tags: css, list

I have been studying CSS. I know that we can use `list-style-type` attribute to set list marker. Can we apply that attribute to a `div` tag?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Just for knowing @Curt. i have searched more, but i can't get anything like this!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes you can. The following causes a `div` tag to resemble itself like a list item:

```
div {display:list-item;}
```

Comment: yeah. Thank you!Now i have got dot image only. can we display the other images like square, circle, our own image?

Comment: Yes You can. Add properties via `list-style-type` attribute. - @user2732006

Comment: yeah. i have followed @Jukka K. Korpela, for my above doubt. i got the result. Thank you

Answer (score 29):

You can set any CSS property on any HTML element. In fact, an element always has all the CSS properties (with the defined initial value as the value, if not set). Not all properties have an effect on all elements in all circumstances, though.

In particular, the definition of the [`list-style-type` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style) says: “*Applies to*:   elements with 'display: list-item'”. Here “applies to” means “has an effect on rendering of”.

Moreover, even if you set `display: list-item` on a `div`, there will be no list marker (like a bullet or a number) to be seen, unless there is space on the left of the element content to accommodate it. You can arrange space using margin properties. Example:

```
div {
  display: list-item;
  margin-left: 1.3em;
  list-style-type: circle;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jJukka K. Korpela. it's working fine. now i can't give up vote. In my question, i asked only for list-item to div tag. so i accepted Nathan Lee's answer.